# TIFF on place edition

Tags: c++, tiff, gdal

I need to rewrite some lines of uncompressed tiff file.
The probles is that I need to do it without copying entire file to another place.

Only way I found is to read the specifications and write my own code to work with tiff files.

libtiff doesn't allow to open file for read and write.
libgeotiff is libtiff based.
gdal also doesn't allow in place editing of files.

Comment: GDAL does in-place updates with the GTiff driver

Comment: Thanks! I'm so glad to fing myself mistaken.

Comment: And are there any notes about unicode support in gdal? I really wanna write unicode app.

Comment: looks like [unicode filename support](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc30_utf8_filenames) was added in [2010](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3766)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDAL is the best library to do this.